# Delivering HTML5 videos on a responsive website

Tags: javascript, html, video, responsive-design, html5-video

I'm wondering what's the best practice to deliver an HTML5 video on a responsive website. I'v converted the video to MP4, WebM and OGG. The files are about 50MB (more or less) what's fine for desktop users, but I'm worried about the ones on mobile phones. I don't want them to get an astronomical bill just for watching some videos on my website.

First I stumbled about Media Querys as described here: http://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/08/html5/responsive-html5-video but they got removed from the HTML5 specs.

The next thing I found was "DASH Streaming" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/DASH_Adaptive_Streaming_for_HTML_5_Video but I don't feel comfortable using it, specialy since the latest demo they are providing https://github.com/Dash-Industry-Forum/dash.js/wiki -> http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/1.2.0/index.html is not working in my browser (Firefox).

Another possibility would be to track the User Agend with PHP and decide what resolution of the video I should deliver, but come on the user Agends are changing all the time and there are for example Android devices with small screens and then there are Tablets with Full HD resolution.

So my current favorite is to load the  element with only one source (.mp4, Full HD) and detect with Modernizer.js what video format is suportet and then decide for the resolution by measuring the screen width (and change it on resize).

But still I'm wondering if there isn't a better way. Any ideas? How are you guys handling this problem?

Comment: sadly today there isn't a good answer. HLS and soon DASH may be viable cross-browser solutions. My 2c would be to detect screen size and decide from that which video source to offer

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Detect with Javascript and then Adjust the source or would you rely on useragend detection on PHP side?

Comment: there are some good libraries out there for detection, but it would require upkeep. screensize detection via JS would at least be self-maintaining